# Android CoordinatorLayout with toolbar cuts behind statusbar, just not hiding fully

Tags: android, toolbar, android-coordinatorlayout

I have been using **drawerLayout** as my root layout. And inside that i have used Coordinator layout with recyclerView to **show/hide** toolbar.

So now tollbar scroll works well with recyclerView, but it only hides half of the toolbar. 
I have seen many questions similar to this issue but nothing helps my cause.

I have attached screenshot below.

**activity_main**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        tools:context="zot.com.myapplication.MainActivity">

        <include layout="@layout/m_toolbar" />

        <include layout="@layout/content_main" />

    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

**m_toolbar**

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/app_bar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/tool_bar">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:elevation="4dp"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways|snap">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:text="Toolbar Title"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="22dp" />


    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

**Activiy Theme**

```
<resources>

    <style name="AppTheme" parent="AppTheme.Base">
        <item name="android:windowContentTransitions">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowAllowEnterTransitionOverlap">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowAllowReturnTransitionOverlap">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowSharedElementEnterTransition">@android:transition/move</item>
        <item name="android:windowSharedElementExitTransition">@android:transition/move</item>
        <!--<item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>-->

        <item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">true</item>
        <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
        <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
    </style>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="android:windowTitleStyle">@color/textColorPrimary</item>
        <item name="android:divider">@color/divider</item>
        <item name="android:actionBarDivider">@color/divider</item>
        <item name="windowActionModeOverlay">true</item>
        <item name="actionModeStyle">@style/ActionMode</item>
        <item name="actionOverflowMenuStyle">@style/drop_down_menu</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

**Toolbar before scroll**

[image: Toolbar before scroll]

**Toolbar after finished scroll -> not hides the toolbar fully**

[image: Toolbar after finished scroll -> not hides the toolbar fully]

**Slider looks good**

[![Slider looks good][3]][3]

Thanks for the help.

Comment: There is something with `fitsSystemWindows` Make it `false` in `coordinatorLayout` and `true` in `AppBarLayout`. Check it.

Comment: No, it makes the statusbar stays there, under this only it shows/hides

Comment: visit this here is complete example. https://github.com/chrisbanes/cheesesquare

Comment: Put it in CollapsingToolBarLayout.

Comment: it doesn't works, not even show/hides.

Comment: Hi.. Make Coordinate layout as parent layout and put Drawer layout as child of it. 
That's the standard way of doing it.

Answer (score 0):

```
 <style name="AppTheme" parent="Base.Theme.MaterialDesign">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">true</item>
    <item name="android:colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="android:colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="android:colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
</style
```

Instead of NoActionBar Theme use Material design theme and specify windowActionBar, and windowNoTitle values.
This might be causing issues in your style.